# What are the possible reasons for a SIP register failure?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx, trunk

I have setup an Elastix box (asterisk/freepbx based) and added a trunk for an external VoIP provider.
When I get to the Asterisk command line interface and type `sip show registry` I always get the same output, `State = Request Sent`.

So, since I can't register with the server I can't make calls.
What are the reasons for the SIP registry state to remain in a status *sent* forever ?

Comment: When a request is sent and no response is received, this can be a firewall issue (port closed). This is general idea and I am just guessing here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a networking / firewall issue... lots of possibilities:

1. Network routing not working from the box: check networking in general
2. SIP provider unreachable
3. Firewall(s) in the way of the outgoing request or the answer
4. A NAT router with SIP options in the way which happens to block internal SIP on port 5060

Time for some network debugging, like pinging the sip server from the freebsd commandline

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing:

1. Module unload chan_sip.so
2. Module load chan_sip.so
3. Sip reload
4. Sip show register, If it remains state=request sent, That means your SIP provider is unreachable.